# VBA HTML Object Library is not parsing Outlook MailItem HTMLBody

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to merge mails by extracting the last message in the a conversation thread. I want to keep the formatting intact so i am trying to get the last message along with the html. I am referencing Microsoft HTML Object Library like this

```
Dim mi As MailItem
Set mi = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Dim bhtml As HTMLBody
Set bhtml = mi.HTMLBody
```

This is giving a type mismatch error.

Comment: Is it error on line 2 where you set the `mi`? You should not use `ActiveExplorer`. You cannot guarantee the item is a `MailItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Regex to extract the last message from the string returned by `oMailitem.body` property. Here is the pattern `(.*(?=(From:.*\nSent:.*\nTo:)))` it is a +ve look ahead i used the first item in match collection and set it in a match object than i extracted the last message like with left function like this `lastmessage = Left(oMailItem.body,oMatch.firstindex)`

Than i wrapped it up in html like this

```
Dim vResult, vLine, sResult As String
vResult = Split(lastMessage, vbCrLf)
For Each vLine In vResult
    sResult = sResult & "</p><p>" & CStr(vLine)
Next
styledLastMessage = "<p>" & sResult & "</p>"
```

And finally appended to the mail i wanted to merge it with like this

```
Dim miBody() As String
miBody = Split(oMailItem.HTMLBody, "<div class=WordSection1>")
miBody(1) = "<p>" & styledLastMessage & "</p>" & "-------" & vbCrLf & miBody(1)
oMailItem.HTMLBody = Join(miBody, "<div class=WordSection1>")
```

Note: After `<div class=WordSection1>` the first message begins.

Answer (score 0):

MailItem.HTMLBody property returns a string, not an HTLBody object.

Comment: You will need to load it into an HTMLDocument object.

Comment: Thank for the advice but i could not find which property to set with the `mi.HTMLBody` here is my updated code `Dim bhtml As HTMLDocument
    Set bhtml = New HTMLDocument  bhtml.? = mi.HTMLBody`